# How can I linq 3 tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I `linq` 3 tables where I can link a student to a school. Tables are: `Students, Depart, School.`

`studentId(pk), departId(fk) departId(pk), schoolId(fk) schoolId(pk)`

Below is linking two tables

```
@foreach (var student in Model.students.Where(s => s.schoolId == item.schoolId))
```

Comment: Please, add the Models and your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

what you want exactly ? you can join them ...

```
var query = (from depart in Model.Depart
             join school in Model.School on depart.departId equals school.departId
             join student in Model.students on school.schoolId equals student.schoolId
             where students.schoolId == item.schoolId
             select new
             {
                 depart,
                 school,
                 student
             });
```

or...

Answer (score 0):

If you have your associations cdonfigured properly, instead of joins, you could also use the associations:

```
var query = from school in Model.Schools
            from dept in school.Departments
            from student in dept.Students
            select new { student, dept, school};
```